# Cannot select multiple files with dojox.form.Uploader in IE8, 9

Tags: dojo

I'm trying to implement the dojox.form.Uploader in order to upload multiple files: 
Here is the way I do:

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
    dojo.require("dojo.parser");
    dojo.require("dijit.form.Button");
    dojo.require("dojox.form.Uploader");        
    dojo.require("dojox.form.uploader.plugins.IFrame");
</script>
<body>
    <div data-dojo-type="dijit.form.Form" id="myMultipleForm1"
        data-dojo-id="myMultipleForm1" action="documentUpload.do"
        method="post" encType="multipart/form-data">
        <div data-dojo-type="dojox.form.Uploader" id="multipleUploader1"
            multiple="true"
            data-dojo-props="name:'uploadedfile[]',
       showInput:'before',isDebug:true">Browse
        </div>
        <button type="submit" data-dojo-type="dijit.form.Button"
            id="submitMultipe1Button">Submit</button>
    </div>
</body>
```

It works fine on FileFox and Chrome, When browsing i can select multiple files but on IE8,9 can select only one.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

IE8/9 don't support the HTML5 file API, and thus don't support drag-an-drop as implemented in Dojox.

IE10 does support the API, so should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use flash. Just add:

```
dojo.require("dojox.form.uploader.plugins.Flash")
```

instead of an iframe, but flash has some limitations.